# Delete element from a list with a pointer

Tags: c++, element

If I have a list in c++, and I have a pointer to one object in that was added to the list, can I delete this element from this list, if I have a pointer to this element?

And whats the best way, that a element in the list can can acces to other elements in a list?

My target ist, that a element in the list has a function to destroy itself.

Comment: You can do it by linking the previous element with the next.

Comment: Yep, so it needs to be a doubly-linked one.

Comment: If it's a single linked list, you just have to track the "previous one I looked at".

Comment: @MatsPetersson If all you have is a pointer, as in the OP's question, there is no "previous". Not even a "start of list" that you can traverse. Anyway, the point is moot, as you shouldn't do it like this anyway. Dino is right and you shouldn't let an element wriggle itself out of its list.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about std containers then when you insert an object you copy it, and object that is stored is just a copy. If you store pointers then you can delete object that is pointed to by this pointer.

You should try and write more elaborate question. If I understand you correctly all I can say is: do not do that. ;] Logic to delete / remove objects from these list should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

`My target is, that a element in the list has a function to destroy itself.`

In this case it is better to have a double linked list (where every node has a pointer to bouth previous and next nodes). If your `currentNode` points to the object you want to delete then first of all add a line like this:

`currentNode->previousNode->nextNode = currentNode->nextNode;`

This will link the node previous to the current one to the node next to the current one.

After this line you can safely delete your `currentNode`